# Symfony: Avoid session on every request

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have an application based on symfony 2.8, and every page request every new session is created.

For example
if /api/check is called 1000 times, 1000 sessions will be created unnecessarily.

firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

```
    api:
        pattern:  /api/
        anonymous: ~
        stateless:  true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            # the user is redirected here when needed to log in
            login_path: security_login_register # URL: /willkommen

            # login handler via FOSUserBundle
            provider: fos_userbundle

            # name of input field of csrf token
            csrf_parameter: _csrf_token

            # token provider
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            # DIRECTION OPTIONS:
            # /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php

            # OPTION 1: if set true, redirect always to default_target_path after login
            # DEFAULT: false
            always_use_default_target_path: false  # DEFAULT: false
            default_target_path: profile_order_list # URL: /profile/orders

            # OPTION 2: if option 1 not enabled, the URL of _target_path will be used for redirection
            # name of input field for redirection for form_login
            target_path_parameter: _target_path

            # OPTIONS 3: if option 1, 2 not enabled and user_refer is true, URL from $request->headers->get('Referer')
            # will be used for redirection
            # disabled using header referrer
            use_referer: false # DEFAULT: false

            # OPTION 4: if nothing found, URL of default_target_path will be used for redirection

            # do not remeber_me with higher security
            remember_me: false

        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: homepage  # URL: /
        anonymous:    true
        switch_user:  true
```

The above block doesn't work in security config. I tried to make /api route stateless but doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: If you read from the session, a session will be started. Are you sure you dont ever read from the session during those requests?

Comment: No i don't touch session on api controller.

Comment: There are many other controllers which has nothing with session(i.e read/write) but still.

Comment: Pretty sure you will need a firewall just for /api.  Your main firewall (as configured) is always going to check the session to see if a user if logged in.  [This might help](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18951) as an example.  There are actually quite a few questions on this.  The fact that you are using the FOSUserBundle is an added complication.  If you still have problems then you might need to start with a fresh empty project and then try to add stuff until the session appears.

Comment: Oops.  You do have a api firewall.  I think your pattern attribute might need a bit of work.